# Redirect visitor to his/her SO profile from my profile

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, user-profile

I want to add a link in my profile which will redirect the visitor to his/her profile when it will be `clicked`.

I came across a profile few week ago(tried to find account but no luck ) which has the same implementation like as written below

`i always upvote (this user) ... etc` where `this user` is a hyperlink which redirected me to my profile (seems cool to me).

Attempts Info

As we know , we can use `html` so it was easy to put a static link there like

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users"> Testing</a>
```

but the implementation required the dynamic code which should appends the user id at the end of the link so i thought of `Javascript` but it can't be used directly , result in the same `JS` code to displayed on my profile along with script tags.

but then i wrote the whole HTML template as and no `script` tag shown in my profile

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
      window.localStorage.getItem('username'); // appear as it is
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users"> Testing</a>
</body>
</html>
```

but still , whatever i write inside script , displayed as it is on my profile screen, even i thought to get the `username` from `cookies` or browser but no luck

1.)  How can get the visitor profile link and use it as `href` link ?

right now it looks like this and clicking on `testing` link, redirect visitor to users tab on SO site which is not desirable

[image]

i would really appreciate any help or direction . Thanks you

Note : you can try this in your profile too , just copy paste the code in your profile section , i am not really asking to visit my profile for views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I been trying since from two days and finally i just managed to do this by just making a small amendment to my code , no `javascript` required. Hurrraah!

All i needed to do was, add **`/current`** at the end of my URL's **`href`** link which will take the visitor to his/her profile when clicked.

so it should be like this

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/current">
```

instead of this

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users">
```

small things do help !